# Как передаются данные из форми во вьюшку методом POST?

Tags: python, html, django

Как передаються данные из форми во вьюшку методом POST? Объясните на пальцах, плз, и если можно, банальный пример (например, передача из формы числа и его "приём" во вьюхе). Спасибо.

пс. гуглы/доки не предгагать, просто прошу показать на пальцах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вьюха с формой:

```
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse

class TheForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

def the_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TheForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("Name is %s " % form.cleaned_data['name'])
    else:
        form = TheForm()

    return render_to_response('template.html', {'form': form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

И показываем в шаблоне:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

То есть забираем все из формы через cleaned_data после проверки is_valid.
Ну и доку на всякий случай https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/ там все прекрасно описано.

Comment: Если форма заполняет все необходимые поля для модели, то можно делать просто  

    element = form.save()
Но это всё есть в доках, пусть человек изучает :)

Comment: Да, читать доки это обязательно :) там и до модельформ дойдет как раз.

Answer (score 1):

Без использования django-froms (как я понял вы просто хотите что то передать в вьюшку)

views.py :

```
def the_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print resquset.POST["name-of-field"] # к словарю resquset.POST обращайтесь по имени поля, там будет то что ввел пользователь

    return render_to_response('template.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template.html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" value="hello!" name="name-of-field" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```