# Ссылки на другую страницу

Tags: python, django

Поясните, пожалуйста! Как сделать на django ссылку на запрос. Например:

```
поле1 поле2 поле3
```

Нажимаем на поле1, берется переменная поле1, отправляется на запрос к базе, и выводим результат в новой html страничке.

Только не пинайте за глупый вопрос, сильно далеко. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаем как обычную ссылку:

```
<a href="first_link/">поле1</a>
```

В urls.py прописываем:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^first_link/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'first.html'})
)
```

UPD: Если, запрос к базе, то вместо `direct_to_template` - указываете необходимый view, и уже из  него рендерите необходимый html.

UPD2: Об этом также было написано: [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32392/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-post)

Comment: Запрос к базе все получается, а как переменную передать к view

     def hisping(request):
        h = SSwAlive.objects.filter(is_deleted=1,sw='???')
        return render_to_response('swhistory.html',{'h':h})

Comment: Насколько я понял, это продолжение вопроса? Тогда уточните пожалуйста, что у Вас не получилось. В комментарии Вы передаете на страницу переменную h - все правильно...

Comment: Да, я передаю на страницу переменную `h`, но чтобы выполнить запрос нужно взять переменную с поле1 и вставить в 

    h = SSwAlive.objects.filter(is_deleted=1,sw='поле1')
    return render_to_response('swhistory.html',{'h':h})

Получается новая страница.

Comment: Ну так понятно стало, а то раньше было не очевидно) На самом деле, это все написано по той ссылке, что я добавил к своему посту напишу сюда, подробно. Сделаем посылку с формы методом пост (для наглядности)

    <form action="first_link/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="sw" value="[[ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ КОТОРОЕ ВАМ НУЖНО ]]" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Поле1">
    </form>

view:
`h = SSwAlive.objects.filter(is_deleted=1,sw=request.POST['sw'])
return render_to_response('swhistory.html',{'h':h})`

И читайте документацию, там это все отлично описано!

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос.

нужно было в urls.py передать вторую переменную в views.py

```
 urls.py
    url(r'^switch/(\S+)/$', 'swhist'),
```

а во views.py её обработать и return в test.html

```
 def test(request, vars):
    res = SSwAlive.objects.filter(is_deleted=1, sw='%s' %vars)
    return render_to_response('test.html',{'res':res})
```